# Why does 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to StackOverflow, I am using python 3.
I am running Python 2 on Python 3.

```
if isinstance(text, str):
-->             text = text.decode(options['inputEncoding'])
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Does anyone know whats wrong with this, I tried to look up everywhere?

This is the default options:

```
defaultOptions = {
        'inputEncoding' : 'utf-8',  # default input encoding for strings
        'outputEncoding' : 'utf-8', # default output encoding
        'substituteChar' : '?', # use to substitute unrecognised characters
        'handleUnrecognised' : UNRECOGNISED_FAIL,   # unrecognised characters:
                                                    # fail, echo or substitute
        'outputASCIIEncoded' : False,   # HTML-encoded ASCII output?                                                
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to run Python 2 code on Python 3? They're not compatible.

Comment: I am using it on Python 3

Comment: It's very hard to be able to answer this without being able to run the code as is. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How to rectify this for Python3

Comment: Python 3 strings are Unicode. They can't be decoded because they don't need to be. They can be *encoded* in a particular coding scheme, such as UTF8. Encoding a string results in a bytestring, which can be *decoded* back into Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would be best served upgrading to Python 3 and referring to the source material for correct formatting: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html